# Random selection with specific conditions Python

Tags: python, random, conditional-statements

I want to select a random number from 0 to 5 a hundred times (in a loop) with the condition that every 10 times all the numbers be selected at least once. Is there a function that can do this? or a specific library?  How should I go about making it happen? (the important part is to make sure all the options are selected in a given specific time).

Comment: Can this be done realistically from pure probabilistic standpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Draw ten numbers, and repeat drawing random numbers until the condition is fulfilled, then move on to the next block of ten. You can easily check whether you got all numbers by comparing the `set` of drawn numbers to the `set` of the desired range. Do note that `random.randrange` excludes the upper limit of `5`, i.e. it samples integers from **[lower, upper)**.

```
import random

def random_blocks(lower=0, upper=5, total=100, blocksize=10):
    if total % blocksize:
        raise ValueError("total has to be evenly divisible by blocksize")
    if upper - lower > blocksize:
        raise ValueError("blocksize has to be greater than or equal to (upper - lower)")
        
    cond = set(range(lower, upper))
    valid = []
    while len(valid) < total:
        temp = [random.randrange(lower, upper) for _ in range(blocksize)]
        if set(temp) == cond:
            valid.extend(temp)
    return valid
```

Comment: Why does it not work when the block size is 12? and is there a mathematical equation for this? and is it possible to implement this online? for example, i am in a loop and i am sampling one agent from 5 at every loop and i have a 100 loops but i want all agents to be selected every 12 steps , thanks

Comment: You can alter the code to work with a blocksize of 12, but then you have to decide how to handle the remainder of 4, because after you have taken 8 blocks, you have selected 96 random numbers, and only 4 remain. Since that is not specified in your post, I have decided to not implement anything, since there is no obvious expected way to do this. Do you want to select 100 elements, or 100 times blocksize elements? Your question suggested the former, but now I have some doubts.

Comment: its 100 elements, but its not a fixed thing, i want to be able to increase the number of selections from 5 to 7 to 9 and the number of elements i can generate, the blocks are only to make sure that all the options are selected in that amount of time

Comment: The function I posted has all these options, but it's still unspecified how you plan to handle the case where `total` is not evenly divisible by `blocksize`.

Comment: i dont understand why the "total" has to be divisible by "blocksize" , i have an experiment where i need to vary the blocksize to reach optimal blocksize

Comment: It does not have to be, but then you have to find an algorithm which fulfills _"I want to select a random number from 0 to 5 a hundred times (in a loop) with the condition that every __n__ times all the numbers be selected at least once"_. Besides, SO is not a coding service, this is a starting point, and it answers the original question. If you want a more general solution, edit your question, please.